# stop the use of a block in RAM

Tags: memory, ram

i'm using Ubuntu 12.04  ,
i noticed that some programs reboots unexpectedly  so   ran memtest86 i found that i have a error in the RAM
my question is :
is there a way to stop the system from using that block of memory that gone bad 
or the only solution is the bay a new one

Answer (score 1):

The only real solution is to replace it. If it is under warranty (as it should be), you should be able to replace it for almost free (may need to pay shipping), by getting an RMA from the manufacturer of it. You'll have to contact their support and do that.

Or you can use the opportunity to upgrade to better quality, faster, or more RAM, if your system isn't maxed out already in that respect.

Answer (score 0):

I know grub has configuration options for bad ram, take a look at /etc/default/grub. However you might want to consult grubs documentation as this might only apply on grub, and not on the booting kernel.